# Is it possible to use _getch() or cin or any input function inside if statement?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use _getch() or cin or any input function inside if statement ?
 I'm trying to create a very simple snake game using c++, I got to make the snake to move but i wanna take the direction input from user while the snake still moves.I'm using visual studio on windows.
`if(_getch())`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Do you know what `if` statement is for? It does not exist so you can put `;` directly after it.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the actual problem. @LogicStuff

Comment: The snake stopped. It stopped the loop. @DimChtz

Comment: You need function to check for key press because `getch()` stops until a line of 1 or more chars is entered. See `kbhit()` function.

Comment: @i486 Thank you, it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

The *expression*, `foo`, say within `if(foo)` is valid if the *type* of the expression `foo` has a valid conversion to the `bool` type.

Given that `_getch()` returns an integral type, it *is* therefore possible to write `if(_getch())`. The `if` will evaluate to `true` if `_getch()` returns a non-zero value, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: What this practically means is that C++ allows it, but it doesn't really make sense. `_getch` returns 0 only if an arrow key on the numerical part of the keyboard is used, and then it is followed by the direction. But that case needs to be combined with `_getch` returning 224 for the regular arrow keys.